# Concrete5 alias of homepage

Tags: alias, concrete5

In the concrete5 dashboard, in the sitemap, you can click-and-drag the icons in the hierarchy to move them around different folders. A prompt then asks if you want to copy, move, or create an alias of this page. This works fine for me when I create aliases of other pages, but I cannot create an alias of the homepage for some reason (the root of the tree.) Is this not a function of C5?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an alias for Home page.
But you can add an external link with `/` or `?cID=1` in url field so it will go to the homepage everytime

Comment: I do not want the user to redirect to the homepage. I want a separate page to replicate all content and changes on the homepages, just like an alias does. This is for analytics tracking, I want a subset of users to go to the alias URL and track their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another page and use various addons to pull content from the home page into the respective areas of the second page, so that the second page automatically replicates all home page content.

The addons of use are:
Global Areas (free)
Parent Area (free, I am the author)
Universal Content Puller (paid, I am the author)